# How do I unwrap without stretching the texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I had this UV unwrapping problem several times already whenever I tried to make things. I think as a beginner I did not really understand how to unwrap properly yet. This time I made a chesterfield sofa.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But many folds and volumes of the sofa made me feel very difficult to unwrap, which may end up with marking hundreds seams manually.

So I used Smart UV project to see how it goes. But as always I could see stretched texture at every corner of the object.

How am I supposed to properly unwrap these kind of objects?

[image]

Comment: you have to make seams in the object. You can take a look at the link below. this guy explains the unwrapping really well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k&t=95s

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It did not really help solve the problem but helped me a lot improve and understand how UV generally works! Sometimes marking seams on my own simply fixes the issue but most times I see the problem not fixed :( I think with time learning blender and UV more, it will gradually be better :) For now, I just ended up applying subsurf modifiers and then decimate, which kinda fixes the problem for anyone wondering. I guess it's not a appropriate way though.